# If I downvote an answer to -1, I don't get the "delete" link until I reload

Tags: feature-request, down-votes, design

Stack Overflow has a bunch of nice UI things that are XHR'd.

However, when I vote to -1 an answer, I need to reload to get the *delete* link. It's not very  obvious, as most things *just work*.

Could we enable the link automatically in this case?

Comment: Please don't use the [meta-tag:bug] tag for things that are not software errors. You are asking for a feature, not reporting a bug.

Comment: @Oded Apologies. I interpreted it as a bug because the behaviour is different, which could have been because it was overlooked.

Comment: Wait, is it your answer getting downvoted, or are you downvoting a question? The title and the question body are contradicting each other.

Comment: @doubleDown he means when he downvote an answer and has more than 20K reputation, allowing instant delete of answers having negative score. Title fixed.

Comment: @doubleDown Whoops. Wasn't thinking correctly :)